# Is there a way to send ETH between two of my metamask wallets

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, react

I try to do it like this but I'm getting an error

```
signer.sendTransaction({
    to: "my_wallet_1",
    from: "my_wallet_2",
    value: wei,
 });
```

and also this one .

```
bankContract.connect(signer).withdrawEther(wei);
```

but the problem with this is it's getting the ETH from the smart contract address and not on the wallet1

I also try the Wallet

```
let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
        "private_key",
        provider
      );

      let tx = {
        to: signerAddress,
        value: wei,
      };

      wallet.sendTransaction(tx);
```

but I'm getting this error `Nonce too high. Expected nonce to be 2 but got 7.` even after resetting the metamask wallet

Comment: How are you connecting to metamask? Are you connected to the correct network?

Comment: yes the connection on metamask works fine. I'm currently connected to the localhost using the `npx hardhat node` and the connection also works on the deployed testnet goerli network.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to reproduce the problem. Perhaps you restarted your node and metamask has the wrong nonce cached. To discard a problem with metamask use a fresh instance in another browser, perhaps reset your contracts, node, etc. even restart your machine.